# Extract specific values or substrings from long string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a long string containing different values/strings i want to extract.

```
String info = "ABHom=1.00;AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=24;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;
              HaplotypeScore=0.9947;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=53.03;MQ0=0;QD=32.49;
              VQSLOD=2.70; culprit=FS";



Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[A][B][h][o][m][=]([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)").matcher(info);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String someNumberStr = matcher.group(1);
        ABhom = Double.parseDouble(someNumberStr);

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[M][L][E][A][C][=]/([0-9]+)").matcher(info);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String someNumberStr = matcher.group(1);
        MLEAC = Integer.parseInt(someNumberStr);
```

I'am new to regex. Is there any smarter way to extract the numbers/strings after the equals sign ?

I'am thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: What is the purpose of `[M][L][E][A][C][=]`?  If you just want to match a specific squence of characters you can just write it as `MLEAC=`; not a big problem but it will make your regex a little easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want to do is to turn your `String` into a `HashMap<String,String>`.

First, you'll need to split  your string around semicolons.  Then, iterate the array that you get, splitting each entry around the equals sign, and adding the result to the `HashMap`.

I suggest you read about the `split` method of the `String` class for how to do this, and also read about the `HashMap` class.  Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html  and post again if you need more help.

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to mention that the string is not always the same. It is possible that variables are missing.

Comment: @ByteCode Im sorry, i forgot to mention that the string is not always the same. It is possible that variables are missing. So i need to assign them to variables if they are in the string

Comment: That's OK.  The `HashMap` will store whatever you give it.  When you go to retrieve them later, if there's an entry missing, then when you try to retrieve it,  you'll just get `null`.

Comment: ABhet = Double.parseDouble(hashMap.get("ABhet")) ? But if the item isn't there it will return null and i get an exception right? How do i asign a value if its there and do nothing if it isn't found ? Have to do this for 800k+ strings!

Comment: So, do it in two steps.  `String ABhetString = map.get("ABhet"); Double ABhet = ABhetString == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(ABhetString);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
String[] split = info.split(";");
for (String string : split) {
       String[] split2 = string.trim().split("=");
       System.out.println(split2[0] +" :" +split2[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is a good idea. Try `info.split(";")[0].split("=")[1]` with some extra boundary check.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in HashMap as follows:

```
String[] parts = info.split(";");
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String s : parts) {
       String[] keyVal = s.trim().split("=");
       hashMap.put(keyVal[0], keyVal[1]);
}
```

and later on you may use hashMap object to get it's values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String info = "ABHom=1.00;AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=24;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;"
            + " HaplotypeScore=0.9947;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=53.03;MQ0=0;QD=32.49;"
            + "VQSLOD=2.70; culprit=FS";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\d+(.\\d+)?)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(info);
    while (matcher.find()) {            
        System.out.println("key: "+matcher.group(1) +" value: "+matcher.group(2));
    }
```

output :

```
key: ABHom value: 1.00
key: AC value: 2
key: AF value: 1.00
key: AN value: 2
key: DP value: 24
key: Dels value: 0.00
key: FS value: 0.000
key: HaplotypeScore value: 0.9947
key: MLEAC value: 2
key: MLEAF value: 1.00
key: MQ value: 53.03
key: MQ0 value: 0
key: QD value: 32.49
key: VQSLOD value: 2.70
```

explanation :

```
\\w mean any character include _ \\w+ means array of characters
\\d mean any digit \\d+ means array of digits
? Matches the preceding element zero or one time. For example, ab?c matches only "ac" or "abc".
```

you said that i want to extract string and numbers , because of this the code above can not extract `culprit=FS` but if you want to extract all pair you should use this code :

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=([^;]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(info);
    while (matcher.find()) {            
        System.out.println("key: "+matcher.group(1) +" value: "+matcher.group(2));
    }
```

output :

```
key: ABHom value: 1.00
key: AC value: 2
key: AF value: 1.00
key: AN value: 2
key: DP value: 24
key: Dels value: 0.00
key: FS value: 0.000
key: HaplotypeScore value: 0.9947
key: MLEAC value: 2
key: MLEAF value: 1.00
key: MQ value: 53.03
key: MQ0 value: 0
key: QD value: 32.49
key: VQSLOD value: 2.70
key: culprit value: FS
```